# How can I place chart directly above the legend? (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is what I achieved so far

http://jsfiddle.net/9r6Lr5gr/3/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
exporting: {
        enabled: false
},
credits: {
        enabled: false
},
tooltip: {
        enabled: false
},
xAxis: {
        lineWidth: 0,
    title: {
            text: ''
    },
    labels: {
            enabled: false
    }
},
yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
            text: ''
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'gray'
        },
        formatter: function(){
                return 'Total: ' + this.total;
        }
    },
    labels: {
            enabled: false
    }
},
legend: {
    reversed: true,
    align: 'left'
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        pointWidth: 30,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'white',
            style: {
                    fontWeight: 'none',
                    fontSize: 15
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Outstanding (due > 7 days)',
    data: [41]
}, {
    name: 'Outstanding (due < 7 days)',
    data: [32]
}, {
    name: 'Overdue',
    data: [15]
}]
});
```

I want to place the bar chart directly above the legend. Also, is it possible the little horizontal line just before the bar chart. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go through comment in code

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r8rtus3q/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        marginBottom: -180, //make charts display at bottom
        events: {
            load: function () {
                // Draw the horizontal line
                var ren = this.renderer,
                    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
                    line = ['M', 550, 0, 'L', 0, 0, 'L', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 'L', 5, 0];

                ren.path(line)
                    .attr({
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                        stroke: colors[1]
                    })
                    .translate(10, 335)
                    .add();

            }
        }

    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    exporting: {
            enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
            enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
            enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
            lineWidth: 0,
        title: {
                text: ''
        },
        labels: {
                enabled: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
                text: ''
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'gray'
            },
            formatter: function(){
                    return 'Total: ' + this.total;
            }
        },
        labels: {
                enabled: false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true,
        align: 'left'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointWidth: 30,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'white',
                style: {
                        fontWeight: 'none',
                        fontSize: 15
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Outstanding (due > 7 days)',
        data: [41]
    }, {
        name: 'Outstanding (due < 7 days)',
        data: [32]
    }, {
        name: 'Overdue',
        data: [15]
    }]
});
```